# How I can declare in .pyi file only part of fields from original module?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, stub

It worked in PyCharm 2016 but it didn't in PyCharm 2017:
[image]

**"Solution":**
PyCharm 2017.2.x support `NamedTuple` from `typing` and I do not need to use `.pyi` files anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT #1:**

I found this issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-18597 and there is an answer:

> PyCharm 2017.1 EAP builds now always prefer stub files over Python files found on the Python path.

Meaning that Pycharm will look for what exists in a `.pyi` file if such a file exists and it will use **only** this as reference. So you don't have another option but to declare all your functions in the .pyi file.

You can find some knowledge on how to avoid potentially annoying warnings and errors in [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#stub-files)

**EDIT #2:**

Yes I can confirm that `from ... import *` does not work as expected in PyCharm and that may be a bug which you can open an Issue for (or if someone succeeded in making this work, please do tell us how)!

I found a workaround based on this quote:

> Modules and variables imported into the stub are not considered exported from the stub unless the import uses the import ... as ... form or the equivalent from ... import ... as ... form.

If you: `from file_a import a as a, b as b ...` then everything gets unmarked as expected, but at `from file_a ...` will give you the following warning:

```
Import resolves to its containing file... (Ctrl+F1) 
This inspection detects names that should resolve but don't. Due to dynamic dispatch and duck typing, this is possible in a limited but useful number of cases. Top-level and class-level items are supported better than instance items.
```

Don't be alarmed, as explained [here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/205819239-Import-problems-with-PyCharm-Import-resolves-to-its-containing-file-Elasticsearch-) it is a warning about possible shadowing of a module name by your file name (which does not apply in your case!)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But i create .pyi files in order to improve completion. In this case, it will only get worse.

Comment: I have edited my answer based on new findings, have a look :)

Comment: I read it. But there has not found answers to the questions ... I tried to write `from file_a import *` in .pyi file. But it didn't work. It is bug or feature?

Comment: Seems to be a bug, open an Issue at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues and probably use this question as a reference! I have reedited my answer to include a temporary workaround for your problem!

Comment: I opened issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-23650#u=1491849729688 . But they think I wrong.

Comment: Then ask for the recommended way to use the stub file and how this relation should be implemented to work as intended.

Comment: I asked https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-23354#comment=27-2078824 . But the solution does not work now and it will broke auto completion...

Comment: You should talk with them on that matter (they are the experts on their software they can figure the problem out)

Comment: Ok. I will try. Thank you.

Comment: Hey @ADR how is this issue resolving? Did my answer helped you? If yes, care to accept it?